# Git Submodule not found by Bamboo

Tags: git, continuous-integration, devops, bamboo

I am trying the continuous integration using bamboo, in my git folder i have a submodule project. While building the .SLN the log shows that he did not find the path of the submodule.

Here is the project folder :
[git repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3uek.png)

and in my bamboo i made : 
Task 1 : Source Code Checkout configuration from this folder
Task 2 : nuget restore
Task 3 : Build the .sln
...

Is there any Task should be added to build the submodule ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you init the submodule after checkout?
If you don't there will just be an epmty folder.

```
git clone https://REPOSITORY
cd SUMBMODULEFOLDER
git submodule init
```

here's the documentation: [Cloning a Project with Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: i did this locally , my problem when i build the project using bamboo

Answer (score 0):

There is a [pretty nice tutorial on bamboo support](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/bitbucket-server-and-cloud-repositories-with-git-submodules-1026524045.html)  site how to do it. I have used the relative paths and SSH keys (Option #1) and it worked really fine and setting it not too complicated.